# Separación de palabras de array de strings Java

Tags: java, array, string, eclipse, split

Tengo el siguiente problema, estoy intentando hacer un programa que lee un archivo de texto, guarda sus lineas en un array de *Strings* y luego tiene que separar las palabras.
Todo esto está dentro de un paquete llamado *figuras*, que tiene una clase `Figura` con algunas hijas: `Rectangulo`, `Elipse`, `Triangulo`, etc. El bloc de notas tiene figuras en este formato:

> circulo:10,1.5,2.5
>
> cuadrado:0.5,-0.5,10

Yo quiero separar la palabra de los números, y después los 3 números, esto en el `void separarNombres()`. Intenté usar `split()` pero no le encuentro la vuelta. Alguna idea? Desde ya, muchas gracias...

PD: Logré llegar hasta la parte de tomar las líneas y almacenarlas en partes de un array.

```
public class LecturaDeArchivo {
  private int contador;
  public String[] figurasString;
    
  public String leerArchivo(String nombre) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("bo.txt"));
    int lineas = 0;
   
    while (reader.readLine() != null) lineas++;
   
    reader.close();
    System.out.println(lineas);
    figurasString = new String[lineas];
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("bo.txt")); 
    String st; 
   
    for(int i=0; i<figurasString.length && ((st=br.readLine())!=null); i++) {
      figurasString[i] = st;
      //System.out.println(nombresFiguras[i]);
    }
    
    contador = lineas;
    return "";
  }

  public String [] figurasNombres = new String [contador];

  public void separarNombres() {
    
  }
```

Comment: donde estan los split que intentaste? se puede hacer con eso.

Comment: Perdón! Lo intenté pero no me llevó a nada, entonces los borré

Comment: Me pregunto por qué usas dos BufferedReader. Puedes ir guardando el texto a la par que cuentas las líneas.

Comment: volve a intentarlo y lo vemos

Comment: La duda que me queda es qué se supone que hace leerArchivo, porque así como está el código, siempre va a retornar una cadena vacía.

Comment: leerArchivo únicamente procesa el texto del bloc de notas y lo mete en el array figurasString con cada elemento i del array siendo una linea del bloca de notas!

Comment: Ah, bueno, entonces vuelvelo de tipo void. Si solo vas a devolver una cadena vacía es mejor que no devuelvas nada. Por cierto, no hace falta que uses la variable contador. Cómo `figurasString` es un arreglo, puedes usar `figurasString.length` para saber su tamaño, que será el mismo número que almacenas en `contador`

Answer (score 0):

lo que debes hacer es dividir el problema, primero separa la palabra de los numeros y luego los numeros, lo que te dejaria dos funciones como las siguiente:

```
   String[] separarPalabrasdeNumeros(String forma){
        String[] resultado=new String[2];
        int indice2puntos=forma.indexOf(":");
        resultado[0]=forma.substring(0,indice2puntos);
        resultado[1]=forma.substring(indice2puntos+1);
        return resultado;
    }
    String[] separarNumeros(String numeros){
        String[] resultado=numeros.split(",");
        return resultado;
    }
```

La primera te dejara un arreglo de strings en el que el elemento 0 es el nombre de la figura y el segundo, son los numeros.
En el segundo caso un arreglo de Strings con los numeros separados en cada elemento.